# how to get one month from now in Calendar data type?

Tags: android, android-calendar

I want to set maximum date in my date picker dialog like this
[image]

as you can see, it requires `Calendar` data type for the input.

I want the max date is always one month from current time. I have tried like this

```
        val now = Calendar.getInstance()
        val currentYear: Int = now.get(Calendar.YEAR)
        val currentMonth: Int = now.get(Calendar.MONTH)
        val currentDay: Int = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

        val oneMonthFromNow = now.add(Calendar.MONTH,1)
```

but `oneMonthFromNow` type is in `unit`, not in `Calendar` data type. so how to dynamically add one month from current date time ?

java or kotlin is ok

Comment: `now.add(Calendar.MONTH,1)` will change `now` .. Why are you assigning it to `oneMonthFromNow`?? `add` method does not return the Calendar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *First thing I would say to not use `Calendar` class, use instead `LocalDateTime`. You will get many articles about how to use this class and why to use.*

---

Even if you want to use Calendar class, then I would say if anything not working or not returning anything, you should look into that class implementation. There must be a way to solve your problem. This way will increase your knowledge as well as debugging skills.

So coming to your solution, you need to use like this

```
    val now = Calendar.getInstance()
    // val currentYear: Int = now.get(Calendar.YEAR)
    // val currentMonth: Int = now.get(Calendar.MONTH)
    // val currentDay: Int = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

    now.add(Calendar.MONTH,1) // Added one month 
    val oneMonthFromNow = now
    // Or 
    // val oneMonthFromNow = now.clone()
    // oneMonthFromNow.add(Calendar.MONTH,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

Use the modern *java.time* classes for all your date-time handling code. If needed to interoperate with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, convert to and from the terrible legacy classes.

```
Calendar c =
GregorianCalendar 
.from(
    LocalDate
    .now(
        ZoneId.systemDefault()
    )                            // Returns a `LocalDate` object.
    .plusMonths( 1 )
    .atStartOfDay(
        ZoneId.systemDefault()
    )                            // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object. 
)
;
```

## *java.time*

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes that years ago supplanted the terrible legacy date-time classes such as `Calendar`.

Get today’s date. This requires a time zone. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ;
```

Or get the JVM’s current default time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;
```

Get today’s date.

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

Get a month later.

```
LocalDate monthLater = today.plusMonths( 1 ) ;
```

If you are interoperating with old code not yet updated fir *java.time*, convert back and forth between legacy and modern classes.

To convert, get the first moment of the day via `ZonedDateTime`. Always let *java.time* determine the first moment, as not all dates in all zones begin at 00:00.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = monthLater.atStaetOfDay( z ) ;
```

Then convert to a `GregorianCalendar` which is also a `Calendar`.

```
GregorianCalendar gc = GregorianCalendar.from( zdt ) ;
```

---

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android]

Answer (score 0):

`now.add(Calendar.MONTH,1)` return type is unit because it is updating your `now`calendar

```
val now = Calendar.getInstance() // it return current calendar
    val currentYear: Int = now.get(Calendar.YEAR)
    val currentMonth: Int = now.get(Calendar.MONTH)
    val currentDay: Int = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

    //now calendar updated by 1 month
    now.add(Calendar.MONTH,1)

    //this will return your upcoming dates
     val nextYear: Int = now.get(Calendar.YEAR)
    val nextMonth: Int = now.get(Calendar.MONTH)
    val nextDay: Int = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
```